# How to have a link in the Navigation Bar in Bootstrap click in Java Script

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a navigation bar with links that lead to different parts to my Webpage, I want it so that in JavaScript I make a command and the link will be pressed and the webpage will be changed.

My Navigation Bar

```js
// Current JavaScript Method (Not Working)
document.getElementById("section2Button").click();
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark justify-content-center fixed-top">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li id="section1Button" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section1">Colleges</a>
    </li>
    <li id="section2Button" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">College Selected</a>
    </li>
    <li id="section3Button" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">About Me</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Instead of linking to an anchor; set your link to another page; i.e. `href="https://google.com"`

Comment: Hey blurfus, thank you for your suggestion,but I want the section of change to be on the same page, so basically I want the webpage scroll down to the section of webpage,

Comment: then you need to create those anchors in your page. i.e. `<h2 id="section3">Section 3</h2>` - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Yes I understand that you have to create anchors but how can I have those be clicked in Javascript?

Comment: not sure I understand why you need to click them via JS but if you do, you need to add an event listener - see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector("#section2Button a").click();
```

You need to query to a tag. And you can put it into any function you want to execute. For example, I put this action into a button.

**You can see full demo here.**

```js
function your_command() {
   // Fixed query
   document.querySelector("#section2Button a").click();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="your_command()">Test command</button>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark justify-content-center fixed-top">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li id="section1Button" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section1">Colleges</a>
    </li>
    <li id="section2Button" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">College Selected</a>
    </li>
    <li id="section3Button" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">About Me</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<h2 id="section1">Section 1</h2>
<h2 id="section2" style="margin-top: 100px">Section 2</h2>
<h2 id="section3" style="margin-top: 100px">Section 3</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an Event Listener.

```
var htmlElement = document.getElementById("section2Button");

htmlElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

see demo

```js
var htmlElement = document.getElementById("section2Button");

htmlElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark justify-content-center fixed-top">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li id="section1Button" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section1">Colleges</a>
    </li>
    <li id="section2Button" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">College Selected</a>
    </li>
    <li id="section3Button" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">About Me</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: make sure you look at the answer by @tartarus - he offers another solution that might suit your needs better :)

Comment: Got it Thank you guys for the help